# Calling stored procedures with parameters in PetaPoco

Tags: sql, petapoco

I want to be able to call a stored proc with named parameters in PetaPoco.

In order to call a stored proc that does a search/fetch:

Can I do something like this:

```
return db.Fetch<Customer>("EXEC SP_FindCust",
new SqlParameter("@first_name", fName),
new SqlParameter("@last_name", lName),
new SqlParameter("@dob", dob));
```

Also, how can I call a stored proc that does an insert?

```
return db.Execute("EXEC InsertCust @CustID = 1, @CustName = AAA")
```

Thanks,
Nac

Comment: I had to set EnableAutoSelect = false.  otherwise petapoco kept trying to put a select clause in from of my EXEC

Comment: If you add a `;` before the EXEC PetaPoco won't add the SELECT:
`.Execute(";EXEC InsertCust @C`

Comment: Adding that semicolon is a little like doing your own SQL injection. I think that `db.EnableAutoSelect = false` is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Update:

I tried the following for fetch and insert and it worked perfectly:

```
var s = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Append("EXEC SP_FindCust @@last_name = @0", lname);
s.Append(", @@first_name = @0", fName);
s.Append(", @@last_name = @0", lName);
s.Append(", @@dob = @0", dob);
return db.Query<Cust>(s);
```

This can be improved further to pass SQL parameters.

Comment: Hi there, that's great thanks, but do you know how I can return the identity from the insert? 

My stored proc is 
 INSERT INTO t_Book VALUES(@BookName, @ParentBookId)
 SELECT @BookId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: That's it: using double @ for the store procedure parameters and single @ for petapoco parameters does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of v6.0.344-beta, PetaPoco now supports stored procedures without needing to use `EXEC`. See https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Stored-procedures

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did the following

```
db.EnableAutoSelect = false;

return db.Fetch<Customer>(@"EXEC SP_FindCust 
@@first_name = @first_name, 
@@last_name = @last_name, 
@@dob = @dob", new {
  first_name = fName,
  last_name = lName,
  dob = dob
});
```

It worked!