# How to return a generic dataset and supplying runtime-known parameters in PetaPoco?

Tags: .net, petapoco

I am binding a result set from a stored procedure to a grid. The stored proc and the number and type of parameters are known during runtime only. I know how to do this in plain ADO.NET. How do I do it using Petapoco? I only used PetaPoco with known classes and proc at design time.

Answer (score 0):

PetaPoco doesn't really provide anything fancy in this area. It pretty much just comes down to building a SQL string and calling it with one of the standard Database methods (Execute, Fetch, etc). You will want to use PetaPoco's SQL builder though (PetaPoco.Sql.Builder); the `Append` method will take care of parameter parsing.

Rather than provide a full example I'll point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960562/62600), which covers it nicely.